# How to disconnect a websocket?

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io, react-redux

I am using socket.io-client for connecting websocket

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
```

After successfull api call i am opening a web socket and i can able to connect to socket and fetch the data,

```
_dashboardStoreChange(type){
  if (type == 'SingleDashboard') {
        let singledashboard = DashboardStore._getSingleDashboard() || {};
        this.setState({ singledashboard }, ()=>{
          this.setState({
            dashboardName: this.state.singledashboard.data.dashboard_name,
           }, ()=>{
            let ns = '/dashboard';
            let access_token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
            let user_id = localStorage.getItem("user_id")+ +new Date();
            let query_data = {access_token : access_token, user_id: user_id};


            const socket = socketIOClient('http://192.168.0.57:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});
            socket.on("dashboard_data", data => this.setState({ socketresponse: data }, ()=>{
              localStorage.setItem("connected_socket_id", this.state.socketresponse.connected_socket_id);
            }));



            let chart_query_data = {"access_token":access_token, 'user_id' : user_id, dashboard_id: this.state.dashboard_id}
            socket.emit('fetch_graph_data', chart_query_data);

            socket.on('dashboard_data', data => this.setState({response: data}, ()=>{

            }));
          });

        });

     }

}
```

After socket connceted successfully i was trying to disconnect a socket from `componentWillUnmount` like below

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    DashboardStore.removeListener('change', this._dashboardStoreChange);
    DataConnectionStore.removeListener('change', this._dataconnectionStoreChange);


    let ns = '/dashboard';
    let access_token = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
    let user_id = localStorage.getItem("user_id")+ +new Date();
    let query_data = {access_token : access_token, user_id: user_id};
    const socket = socketIOClient('http://192.168.0.57:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});


    let disconnect_query_data = {access_token : access_token, user_id: user_id}
    socket.emit('disconnect_socket', disconnect_query_data);
}
```

But as i am using again socket api another socket is geting opened, without calling the how can i disconnect.

as in  `socket` variable using `socketIOClient` I am calling socket api.
after componentwillunmount is called i need to disconnect the socket.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to use `socket.disconnect()` or `socket.close()`.

You can learn more about disconnecting and connecting in the documentation [here.](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-close)

**Below is the code to save socket to state so you can use it later on to call.**

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.initSocket();
}

initSocket() {
   const socket = socketIOClient(ENTER SOCKET URL HERE);

   socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log("Connected");
    });

   this.setState({ socket });
}
```

**Use the socket from state to call the .disconnect function**

```
const { socket } = this.state;
socket.disconnect();
```

**If you are calling the disconnect function in another component pass the socket from state via props or redux**

Answer (score 0):

did you try to make your socket an attribute of your component class ?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://192.168.0.57:9000'+ns,{query:query_data});
   }
  // some other code...

  compomnentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
}
```